# deploy go api does not send any response

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I've created a `Go` API and deploy but when i see the logs there is no `Println` and no response is send to the client

the `main`:

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/v1/", handler)
    appengine.Main()
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method != "GET" {
        http.Error(w, "not allowed", http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
        return
    }
    ...
}
```

the `yaml` file:

```
runtime: go
api_version: go1.8
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
```

the url that i'm accessing:
`myapp.appspot.com/v1/param`

(what is this _go_app?)

the problem is that if i pass a "POST" request the error works just fine, but if i make a valid request the response take forever.

full code: https://goplay.space/#yiIp42FKzzj

Comment: Does the code in the `...` send a response?   Where are the `Println`s?

Comment: @ThunderCat i've included a link with full code

Comment: Use the logger to write to the logs: https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine/log.  Does it hang when running locally?  If so, send the process a SIGQUIT to dump the stacktraces.  That my point to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In AppEngine you must use the [AppEngine logger](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine/log), passing in the context from the request.

Example from the godoc:

```
c := appengine.NewContext(r)
query := &log.Query{
    AppLogs:  true,
    Versions: []string{"1"},
}

for results := query.Run(c); ; {
    record, err := results.Next()
    if err == log.Done {
        log.Infof(c, "Done processing results")
        break
    }
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf(c, "Failed to retrieve next log: %v", err)
        break
    }
    log.Infof(c, "Saw record %v", record)
}
```

Comment: sorry, i did not understand and i think that your answer is not relationed to the question; the problem is that if i pass a "POST" request the error works just fine, but if i make a valid request the response take forever

Comment: Ah, I thought your question was about the lack of a `Println` showing up.

Comment: Can you paste the rest of the function's code into your question? I'm not clicking on a that link, sorry!

Comment: no dude, sorry, the code is too long.
the link is a better version of play.golang.org don't worry